# Simple MongoDB query

Tags: mongodb

Trying to understand MongoDB,

this query does not insert anything into db:

```
> names = ['Serg', 'Bob', 'Sean', 'Sophia'];
[ "Serg", "Bob", "Sean", "Sophia" ]
> for (i=0; i<names.lenght; i++) db.people.insert({ name: names[i], age: Math.round(Math.random()*60) });
> db.people.find()
>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because of typo: `lenght -> length`

And maybe it's required to explicitly create collection like `db.createCollection('people');`

Comment: So, embarrassed..... ))) But the thing that come to my mind right away is why mongo shell didn't give me any errors??

Comment: @Vor It won't give an error due to object property accession, it instead defines `lenght` as a property of the names object and returns it

Comment: @Vor no problem, I had to try it myself before I noticed :)